# Exception handling in webservice application

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a service-based application using Hibernate + Spring (through JPA) and CXF for WebService implementation. It has two layers, a Service layer (which is also the WebService implementation), and the DAO layer which implements persistence.

All my DAO exceptions are wrapped through Spring's own `DataAccessException`.

I want to handle all possible exceptions (including both WSDL and JAX-XX exceptions like `Unmarshalling Error` and such) in my WebService layer in order to return a custom SOAP fault with my own messages, but I don't want to try-catch all my methods.

What is the right way of doing it? I've read about CXF interceptors which allow me to introduce a custom fault but it does not work on WSDL exceptions...

Some `DataAccessException`, also, I want to handle differently, like for instance if the user creates an entity with a name that already exists (and is marked as UNIQUE) I want to let the user know about this particular error. How can I do that?

What does the standard say about this? How different are for this matter Checked and Unchecked exceptions?